# VBA - Prevent Excel 2007 from showing a defined names message box?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a Excel 2007 workbook that will contain a macro to save the current sheet (a template) as

1. a PDF file (no problem)
2. a Excel 97-2003 file (problem)

When saving the Excel file a messagebox appears asking about

*"Defined names of formulas in this workbook may display different values when they are recalculated...Do you want Excel to recalculate all formulas when this workbook is opened?".*

The user can then select Yes/No and then the file will save.

How do I disable the messagebox from appearing?
The default answer would be 'No'.

My [code](http://www.rondebruin.nl/saveas.htm) for saving:

```
Sub saveAs_97_2003_Workbook(tempFilePath As String, tempFileName As String)
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim SaveFormat As Long

    'Remember the users setting
    SaveFormat = Application.DefaultSaveFormat
    'Set it to the 97-2003 file format
    Application.DefaultSaveFormat = 56

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook
    Destwb.CheckCompatibility = False

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs tempFilePath & tempFileName & ".xls", FileFormat:=56
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    'Set DefaultSaveFormat back to the users setting
    Application.DefaultSaveFormat = SaveFormat
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this around the With, End With:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Destwb
    ...
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Should suppress the message, but not sure if it'll default the way you want.

Comment: Seems to work fine - It appears to be selecting Yes as a default but the resulting saved file looks ok.